# Handling stdin with tornado

Tags: python, pipe, tornado

How to listen for events that happen on stdin in Tornado loop?

In particular, in a tornado-system, I want to read from stdin, react on it, and terminate if stdin closes. At the same time, the Tornado web service is running on the same process.

While looking for this, the most similar I could find was handling streams of an externally spawned process. However, this is not what I want: I want to handle i/o stream of the *current* process, i.e. the one that has the web server.

Structurally, my server is pretty much [hello-world tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/helloworld/helloworld.py), so we can base the example off that. I just need to add an stdin handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `add_handler` method on the `IOLoop` instance to watch for events on `stdin`.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
import sys

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        self.finish("foo")

application = Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

def on_stdin(fd, events):

    content = fd.readline()

    print "received: %s" % content

if __name__ == "__main__":

    application.listen(8888)

    IOLoop.instance().add_handler(sys.stdin, on_stdin, IOLoop.READ)

    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's enough to get the data in the socket. However, I'm having a hard time to catch the 'stdin closed' event. Posted a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741435/handling-closing-of-stdin-with-tornado

Comment: Gives me `ogram Files (x86)\Python35-32\workspace\webSocketServer.py ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\workspace\webSocketServer.py", line 38, in <module>
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_handler(sys.stdin, on_stdin, tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 719, in add_handler
    fd, obj = self.split_fd(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 648, in split_fd
    return fd.fileno(), fd
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno`